# 'Bad repeat count' while inputting a file, FORTRAN

Tags: file-io, runtime-error, fortran90

I am trying to read a file into my code.
there are 2 subroutines, one which writes a file and the other which reads it.
the writing part was:

```
write(*,*)'entered refile, shall make file'
ileunitA=int(presentstep)
write(fname,1012)ileunitA
1012 format('DATA_',i6.6,'.dat')

write(fnam,1112)index
1112 format('pp',i3.3)

open(UNIT=ileunitA,FILE=fname)

!variables from module global
write(ileunita,*)u,v,w,pc,p,p0,rho1,gam,con
write(ileunita,*)aip,aim,ajp,ajm,akp,akm,ap,ap0
write(ileunita,*) scon,smomu,smomv,smomw
...
```

The reading part was as follows(in another subroutine):

```
ileunita=25;
open(unit=ILEUNITA,file='DATA_010500.dat')

!variables from module global
read(ileunita,*)u,v,w,pc,p,p0,rho1,gam,con
read(ileunita,*)aip,aim,ajp,ajm,akp,akm,ap,ap0
read(ileunita,*) scon,smomu,smomv,smomw
...
```

When I run the code, it shows the following error:

At line 3682 of file bub2.f90 (unit = 25, file = 'DATA_000001.dat')

Fortran runtime error: Bad repeat count in item 1 of list input

Can anyone help me figure out what could be the problem? And what is 'repeat count'. What is a 'bad' repeat count? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Guessing a little (you could show the text in the problematic line in your question...), but you are using list directed input (and output) with the `*` as the second specifier in the read (and write) statements.  List directed input allows multiple fields that have the same value to be represented using the syntax `r*c`, where `r` is a numeric repeat count and `c` is the value to be repeated.

If any of your output items generate a field that contains a `*` then that could be confusing the processing of input.

(It is permissible (though rare) for a processor to represent multiple output fields that have the same value using a repeat count, for example `WRITE (unit,*) 23, 23, 23, 23` could result in an input file that contains the text `4*23`.)

List directed input also has some other features, such as the handling of delimiter characters, the `/` character causing input processing to terminate and the possibility and handling of null values.  Some of these features may surprise those not familiar with the rules (which are inspired by typical short cuts taken when input was submitted via punched cards), which why it is often better to avoid list directed input and output and use an explicit format instead.

If any of your data fields are of type character you should consider using a non-default DELIM mode to avoid any special characters within the character variable value from confusing the input processing.